# How do I force PM2 to update my meteor app server-side after a deployment?

Tags: ubuntu, meteor, nginx, pm2

I've wrapped my Meteor website using "pm2-meteor". The settings are setup and the initial deploy worked just fine. It's setup to work with Nginx on a Digital Ocean Ubuntu server.

When I run a "pm2-meteor deploy", it says it's done, and the bundle on the server is updated (I checked the "modified at"-timestamp) but the code on the actual website "www.example.com" remains unupdated.

I've tried reloading & restarting both PM2 and Nginx but nothing seems to help.

My config:

```
{
  "appName": "example",
  "appLocation": {
    "local": "/Users/example/Documents/Personal/Projects/base"
  },
  "meteorSettingsLocation": "../.deploy/settings.json",
  "meteorBuildFlags": "--architecture os.linux.x86_64",
  "env": {
    "ROOT_URL": "http://example.be",
    "MONGO_URL": "mongodb://localhost:27017/example",
    "PORT": 8080
  },
  "server": {
    "host": "199.199.199.1",
    "username": "user",
    "password": "1234",
    "deploymentDir": "/opt/pm2",
    "loadProfile": "",
    "nvm": {
      "bin": "~/.nvm/nvm.sh",
      "use": "4.7.2"
    },
    "exec_mode": "cluster_mode",
    "instances": 1
  }
}
```

The PM2 status of my app:

```
┌────────────────────────┬────┬─────────┬───────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬─────┬───────────┬──────────┐
│ App name               │ id │ mode    │ pid   │ status │ restart │ uptime │ cpu │ mem       │ watching │
├────────────────────────┼────┼─────────┼───────┼────────┼─────────┼────────┼─────┼───────────┼──────────┤
│ Example │ 0  │ cluster │ 22944 │ online │ 3       │ 11m    │ 0%  │ 69.7 MB   │ disabled │
└────────────────────────┴────┴─────────┴───────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴─────┴───────────┴──────────┘
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: looking into this now as well. I'll update with any info

Answer (score 0):

- pm2-meteor reconfig -> will not deploy file changes - only deploys env var changes!
- pm2-meteor deploy -> will deploy file changes but not env var changes!
- pm2-meteor deploy --reconfig -> will deploy file changes and env changes

Further info: https://github.com/andruschka/pm2-meteor/issues/62#event-1078165006